# How to calculate the expectation of three independent random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume we have three independent random variables A, B and C. The distribution for A,B and C are known(In this case just assume they are all beta distribution with different parameters). I want to calculate the expectation of E(A∩B∩C).

Is this equation E(A∩B∩C)= E(A)E(B)E(C) true or false ?.

Is the expectation E(A∩B∩C) mean same as E(A and B and C) ?
Please let me know if I'm right.

Comment: I think you mean $\mathbb{E}(ABC)$ in which case $\mathbb{E}(ABC) = \mathbb{E}(A).\mathbb{E}(B).\mathbb{E}(C)$ only if the random variables A, B and C are independent.

Comment: so the equation E(A∩B∩C)= E(A)E(B)E(C) is true

Comment: Just to clarify @AdeelMahmood's comment, the three variables need be be independent, not just pairwise. In general, if $X_1,...,X_n$ are independent and the expectations exist we have $E[f(X_1)...f(X_n)] = E[f(X_1)]...E[f(X_n)]$.

Comment: $A \cap B \cap C$ makes sense for events though not random variables.  Events do not have an expectation, though they do have a probability

Comment: The notation $E[A]$ is a bit unusual, either $P(A)$ or $E[1_A]$ are more usual?

Comment: copper.hat -> ok,but what if all the variables are pairwise Independent between each other

Comment: Henry-> i don't understand ?

Comment: @AhmedAzize to notify users of your comments, you should write the comments with an @ sign in front of their names.